# Download a page and calculate throughput in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c

I have to write code to download from a website and then calculate the throughput of the download every 3 seconds in bytes/sec. How can I do this? 
Let's say I download the website but then I need to store it in some sort of mutable array which stores bytes and then divide its length by 3 after every 3 seconds. What timer can I use that will help me know the throughput?

Also, the data needs to be stored in bytes so which array type can I use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read up on [NSURLConnection](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLConnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html).  If you implement it's [delegate](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLConnectionDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/NSURLConnectionDelegate), you'll get called back as the data is received.  NSURLConnection provides a method to make the request in one shot, but this way you can present partial results to the user.

Create three properties to keep state:

```
@property(nonatomic, strong) NSDate *start;
@property(nonatomic, assign) NSInteger bytesSoFar;
@property(nonatomic, assign) float throughputSoFar;

- (void)start {
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com/"]];
    NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response {
    self.start = [NSDate date];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {
    NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
    self.bytesSoFar += [data length];
    self.throughputSoFar = self.bytesSoFar / [now timeIntervalSinceDate:self.start];
    // update the UI with progress
}
```

When you get connectionDidFinishLoading, self.throughputSoFar will be the final throughput.

Answer (score 2):

Read the [*URL Loading System Programming Guide*](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/URLLoadingSystem.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000165i) to learn about `NSURLConnection`.  If you only want to calculate that simplistic definition of “throughput”, you don't even need to store the actual bytes received, although `NSURLConnection` will do that.  You just need to count the number of bytes received.

To measure the time it takes to receive the file, call `[NSDate timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate]` just before (or just after) starting the `NSURLConnection`.  Then call it again when the connection completes.  Subtract.  The difference is the download duration in seconds.

Read [*Timer Programming Topics*](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#Documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Timers/Articles/usingTimers.html) to learn about `NSTimer`.  Use one to notify you that three seconds have passed.